# Why does this code create invalid rsa public keys in my node.js service?

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, rsa, cryptojs

I am writing a service in node.js that will run online and distribute keypairs to other servers of mine (runs php) and to my clients (written in c#). What already works is creating the key and sending it over to the php service, which stores it in a mysql database and uses it later to encrypt messages. The keys arrive fine (to my eye) and i can retreive them from the database later on. This seems fine.

My problem is that the keys all seem to be invalid when i try the encrypting part in php using

```
openssl_public_encrypt($,$,$);
```

Am i breaking the keys upon transmission? (i don't think so, they seem to be invalid when i copy them from the key-creation-service's console and test them)

Am i breaking them when storing them in mysql? (Tried varchar and blob as datatypes, same result)

Am i doing the key-creation wrong of sorts?

Here's how they are created:

```
getKeyPair() {                                                                                                              
79         const crypto = require('crypto') 
80    
81         const { publicKey, privateKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
82                 modulusLength: 4096,
83                 publicExponent: 3,  
84                 publicKeyEncoding: {      
85                         type: 'pkcs1', 
86                         format: 'pem'   
87                 },                  
88                 privateKeyEncoding: {   
89                         type: 'pkcs1',    
90                         format: 'pem'  
91                 }    
92         })  
93           
94         console.log(publicKey)         
95         console.log(privateKey)    
96              
97 
98         return [publicKey,privateKey];   
99   },
```

This is how i send them over:

```
 async sendPublicKey( wguid, publicKey ) {     
48         try {          
49                 var qs = require('qs')  
50                                
51                 return await axios.post( 'http://someurl.example',
52                         qs.stringify({    
53                                 apiKey: 'some1key4example',      
54                                 otherApiKey: 'some3Other5key', 
55                                 setKey: '',   
56                                 guid: 123456798, 
57                                 rsaKey: publicKey  
58                         }),   
59                         {    
60                                 headers: {  
61                                         'Host': 'http://someurl.example' 
62                                 }       
63                         })     
64                         .then( (response) => {      
67                                 return response.data    
68                         })    
69         }  
70         catch(error) {  
71                 console.log('error trying to post public key') 
72                 console.log(error) 
73                 return error 
74         }     
75   }
```

This is how i store the keys on the other service:

```
else if( isset($_POST["setKey"]))
218 {
219         if( $_POST["otherApiKey"] != $otherApiKey )
220         {
221                 Error( "Unauthorized. You may not set a Key", "Unauthorized. You may not set a Key", 401);
222         }
223         $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT $guidField FROM $keysTable WHERE $guidField = :postGuid");
224         $stmt->bindParam(":postguid", $_POST["guid"]);
225         $stmt->execute();
226         if( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 )
227         {
228                 Error( "Conflict. Cannot override Key.", "Conflict. Cannot override Key.", 409);
229         }
230
231         $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $keysTable VALUES( :postGuid, :postKey )");
232         $stmt->bindParam( ":postGuid", $_POST["guid"] );
233         $stmt->bindParam( ":postKey", $_POST["rsaKey"] );
234         $stmt->execute();
235         echo("key set success");
236 }
```

And this is the part where i try to encrypt something with that key and it fails:
(Gives me "PHP Warning:  openssl_public_encrypt(): key parameter is not a valid public key in ...")

```
 61         $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT $keyField FROM $keysTable WHERE $guidField = :postGuid");
 62         $stmt->bindParam(":postGuid", $_POST["guid"]);
 63         $stmt->execute();
 64         if($stmt->rowCount() <= 0) ERROR("Forbidden. No token granted.", "Forbidden. No token granted.", 403);
 65         if($stmt->rowCount() > 1 ) ERROR("Internal Server Error", "Internal Server Error", 500);
 66
 67         $secret = "somesecret for example purposes";
 68
 69         $publicKey = $stmt->fetchColumn();

 76         $pubKeyRes = openssl_get_publickey($publicKey);

 78         $cypher = '';
 79         openssl_public_encrypt($secret, $cypher, $pubKeyRes);
```

Here's a sample key taken from the key-generation-services logfile:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Pretty shure i am missing something obvious here!!!
I hope anyone can point me in a direction of where to look - i have been stuck on this for days now...

I tried to make a key in node.js, send the public part via http POST request to a php/mysql server. On the server i stored it in the database. Retreived it later to encrypt some secret with it. got "not a valid key" back.

I tried storing it as varchar() and as blob in mysql.

I tried with and without preparing the key with openssl_get_publickey($publicKey);

I tried trimming and chunking the result from the database to 'fix' the key.

I tried base64encode on it.

Nothing worked so far....

Comment: Try changing the `type` in the `publicKeyEncoding` option from `pkcs1` to `spki`.

Comment: Update: Key-generation-code worked when i only changed the publicKeyEncoding to `spki`. privateKeyEncoding remains `pkcs1`. This also makes the cypher-generation work in the php-part. Thanks again @PresidentJamesK.Polk - mind a word of explanation on what i just did? **Why does it work now?**  I will post a proper answer as soon as i get the de-cyphering with the private key working as well. (or do you want to do it, PresidentJames? I will approve your answer if you like)